# Unable to submit CSV file to uploader

Tags: php, csv

I've made a CSV uploaded where the user must tell the program the exact name of certain columns in the CSV file so it can access and grab data to store in database.  I have some error messages where whenever they don't fill something out that is necessary it will take them back to form to fix what ever mistakes they made.  The issue is it always takes me back and I don't really know why.

Code for Uploader ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}

function returnBack(){

    header("Location:csvuploader/csvuploaderform.php?seterror=1");
    exit;

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /*******************************GET NAME OF COLUMNS IN CSV FILE *********************************************************/
    if (empty($_POST['files'])){
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
        returnBack();
    }if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['phone'])){
        returnBack();
    }
    $file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];   

    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");

    $firstname_index = array_search($_POST['firstname'],$fileop);
    if (empty($firstname_index)){
        returnBack();
    }
    $lastname_index = array_search($_POST['lastname'],$fileop);
    if (empty($lastname_index)){
        returnBack();
    }
    $email_index = array_search($_POST['email'],$fileop);
    if (empty($email_index)){
        returnBack();
    }
    $phone_index = array_search($_POST['phone'],$fileop);
    if (empty($phone_index)){
        returnBack();
    }

    /***********************ASSIGN COLUMN VALUES TO ACCORDING VARIABLES AND INSERT THEN INTO CSV TABLE IN DB *************************************/


    while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
    {
        $firstname = $fileop[$firstname_index];
        $lastname = $fileop[$lastname_index];
        $email = $fileop[$email_index];
        $phone = $fileop[$phone_index];

        $insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csv (firtname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone')");
        $insertdata->execute();
    }
    if ($insetdata){
        echo "Successfully Uploaded. Thank you.";   
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

UPDATED ---------------------------

form code

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form method="post" action="csvuploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>CSV Uploader </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of First Name Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="fisrtname" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Last Name Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="lastname" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Email Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Name of Phone Number Column </td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="phone" type="text" ><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Need Exact Name</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="294"><input type="file" name="files" /><?php 
    $setError=$_GET['seterror']; 
    if($setError == 1){
    echo "<span class='errorMsg'>Select a File</span>";
    }
        ?></td>
</tr>
<br />
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML code as well? I mean the form.

Comment: Variant of this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999305/unable-to-submit-csv-file-to-uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your data file look, but you might want to use `trim` on `fgetcsv`ed array values, because the last values are very likely to include a line-end:

```
$fileop=fgetcsv($handle);
$fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);
/*recognize index*/
while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle))!==false)
{
    $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);
    $firstname=$fileop[$firstname_index];
    /*insert into DB*/
}
```

**Edit**:

Oops, seems I missed something...you're using

```
if(empty($firstname_index))
```

in your code, but if, for instance, `array_search($_POST["firstname"],$fileop)` returns 0 (which is the first index in an array), your `empty($firstname_index)` will be `TRUE`, and you will be kicked back.

You should use

```
if($firstname_index===false)
```

instead (in all four indexes). [PHP Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

**Edit #2**:

Also, it's better to make you title-matching case-insensitive:

```
$fileop=fgetcsv($handle);
$fileop=array_map("strtoupper",array_map("trim",$fileop));
$firstname_index=array_search(strtoupper($_POST["firstname"]),$fileop);
if($firstname_index===false) returnBack();
/*and all four indexes*/
```

Comment: The data file I will never know so they tell us what is the name of there firstname column,lastname, etc.  Then it checks (index) to see if that value exist. If it does it will loop through and add all values to db.  I will try what you said and let you know.

Comment: I still get kicked back to form - It keeps sending back error using the returnBack function

Comment: @DavidBiga Then you should use some debug technique and see what's wrong...did you use both `trim` and FASLE checking at the same time? And have you considered making your title-matching case-insensitive?

Comment: I'm about to look - could you enlighten me with the case-insensitive match making because I probably should do that.

Comment: Hey real quick.  Just found out if I use `if (empty($_POST['files'])){
        returnBack();
    }`

Comment: It will shoot me back anyways so the issue is there but if I use `if (isset($_POST['files'])){
        returnBack();
    }` it will bypass but then for the next empty statement it runs that as empty.

Comment: @DavidBiga Glad that inspired you :) Personally I would not check `$_POST["file"]` since it's better to check `empty($_FILES["file"])`

Comment: So I did that but it tells me file is still empty and I do not know why.

Comment: @DavidBiga At this point you can pretend you didn't notice that and just cheer the problem is solved...:D

Comment: Haha IF you can't that fine I really do appreciate the help! The only error is using `if (empty($_FILE['files'])){
  echo "files is empty";
 
  //returnBack();
 }`

Comment: Everything is good and ready my issue was i didnt use FILES instead of FILE :(  Thanks again for all your help A+++++